# How to convert a timestamp field to int8? Or just drop the column and make a new one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, ddl, epoch

I have a PostgreSQL table with a column of type `timestamp`. I had included this column a while ago just in case I wanted to use it for something in the future. I am now looking to convert it into an `int8` and use it as an epoch time column. All rows of the table have this column set to `null` at the moment. When I try to alter the row using:

```
ALTER TABLE public.new_ambient_data
ALTER COLUMN sensor_date TYPE int8 USING sensor_date::int8;
```

I get the error:

> ```
> ERROR: cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to bigint
> ```

Is it better to just drop the column and make a new one of the data type that I want, or is here a better SQL script to convert the empty `timestamp` column to an `int8`.

Note: The table in question has over a million rows in it.

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the objective is undefined without clearing up what that `int8` is going to represent. Seconds since the epoch? Milliseconds? Microseconds? (Won't matter in your particular case with all NULL values, but the next reader might be misguided.)

Next, in Postgres there is no cast defined for `timestamp` --> `bigint` (basically for the same reason). You need a valid expression for the `USING` clause.

**Assuming you want microseconds** because that's preserving the original microsecond resolution of Postgres timestamps, this will do the job:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.new_ambient_data
   ALTER COLUMN sensor_date TYPE int8 USING (extract(epoch FROM sensor_date)*1000000)::int8;
```

Notably, the Postgres epoch for timestamps starts at 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, unlike the UNIX epoch starting at 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. But [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) returns the UNIX epoch (which can be converted back to `timestamptz` with [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)). So just converting the internal value wouldn't do.

For your particular case (**all values NULL**), it's simpler to use `text` as stepping stone. Every type can be cast from and to `text` (as long as the value is compatible).

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.new_ambient_data
   ALTER COLUMN sensor_date TYPE int8 USING sensor_date::text::int8;
```

And yes, it's probably cheaper to convert the column in place, than to drop and recreate it. While the column is all NULL, the operation is very cheap either way, as there is no actual tuple data, only a bit in the NULL bitmap. Neither way will trigger a table rewrite.

A newly added column always goes to the end of the columns list, while the converted one stays in place. Depends on what you want.

Finally, **don't do it** at all. The data type `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) is typically superior to storing temporal information as generic `bigint` in multiple ways. See details in Laurenz' answer!

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [How to get the date and time from timestamp in PostgreSQL select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363023/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-from-timestamp-in-postgresql-select-query/17371452#17371452)
- [How to round off milliseconds value from timestamp(0) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002714/how-to-round-off-milliseconds-value-from-timestamp0-in-postgresql/55010430#55010430)

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to dissuade you from doing that. It is much better to use a `timestamp` column than to use a numeric column:

- the values can more easily be understood by a human
- you can make use of date arithmetic, so you don't lose anything:

  `timestamp - timestamp → interval`

  `timestamp + interval → timestamp`

  `interval / double precision → interval`

  This makes your queries more readable
- if you use `timestamp with time zone`, you can have PostgreSQL handle time zone conversions for you
- useful functions like `date_part` and `date_trunc` (and `date_bin` from v14 on!) to truncate the values and extract individual components

Internally, a timestamp is stored as a number anyway, so you don't lose performance.

The actual conversion is given in Erwin's answer, so I won't repeat that here.